# When should I make a subclass instead of instances of a class?

Tags: python, oop

How do I know when to make something a class instead of an instance of a class? For example:

If I'm creating a space game (I'm not), and I want the environment to be the Universe, I'd write:

```
class Universe:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
```

Now let's say I'd like to fill my Universe with Galaxies, so I'd make a Galaxy subclass, with size and name parameters:

```
class Galaxy(Universe):
    def __init__(self, size, name):
        super().__init__(self):
    self.size = size
    self.name = name
        pass
```

Next, I'd like to make Planets. If this were the case, I should make a subclass of the Galaxy subclass right?

```
class Planet(Galaxy):
    def __init__(self, type, climate):
        super().__init__(self, size, name):
    self.type = type
    self.climate = climate
        pass
```

From here I'd like to make the Planet types, or "families". What's the best way to go about this? Another subclass of a subclass? Each planet will contain resources that are unique to that family of planets. Should I then make this:

```
class PlanetType(Planet):
    resources = []
    def __init__(self, resources):
        super().__init__(self, type, climate) 
    self.resources = resources
        pass
```

Comment: The `Planet->SubPlanet` design seems logical but I'm not sure about `Universe->Galaxy->Planet`. For example, a `Universe` can have a field `galaxies[]` that is a list of the galaxies in that universe. But if `Galaxy` inherits from `Universe` it too will have `galaxies[]` but that doesn't make sense as a galaxy does not contain other galaxies. (Not arguing the point of colliding galaxies).

Comment: The way to think of base classes is they have an "is-a" relationship.  Does "A Galaxy is a Universe" make sense?  But a Universe "has-a" galaxy, which indicates a member variable.

Comment: I think the same could be said about planet families. That is not a subclass of planet, but rather a collection of planets. That collection (list or dictionary or what-have-you) could be encapsulated in a class as you will likely have multiple implementations of families of planet objects...

Comment: As a programming question in general, this is very well put. With that said, asking a question in the form "What's the best way to go about this?" indicates that it will probably be answered with opinions. Such questions are typically considered off-topic on StackOverflow. If this does get closed, don't be discouraged, it's a great question, and you can consult [ask] for ideas on how to [edit] it to make it more on topic. If this question is never closed, you can disregard this comment.

Comment: There is a concept of nested or inner classes in python and it might make sense to have `galaxy` as a nested class of `universe` and `planet`, in turn, nested inside of `galaxy`. You are then also, at the `universe` class level to have a dictinary or list of `galaxies` implemented from the nested `galaxy` class. It isn't necessary to nest like this, but it may give you the structure, in code, that I think you are seeking with your subclass concept. Although this may break down if your planet families are going to span galaxies or universes.

Comment: Good question, just hard to answer in a way that is valuable for StackOverflow to keep around on their servers ;)

Comment: @JNevill: I wouldn't actually nest the classes (if someone wants to make a planet, they have to do `Universe.Galaxy.Planet("gas", "warm")`?), but yes, having each larger unit contain a collection (`list`, `set`, whatever) of the next smaller unit as an attribute of the larger unit's instances makes sense.

Answer (score 6):

So this is not specific to Python, it's more of a core idea of OOP(Object Oriented Programming)

> How do I know when to make something a class instead of an instance of a class?

Answer : In your example Universe is the superclass , and you want to create the notion of Planets. If Planet inherits (subclass) from Universe that means they have an "is" relationship. I'm going to bring another popular example here to illustrate my point.

Let's say you have a class Car. Maserati would be a subclass(would inherit) from this superclass because a maserati IS a Car.
If you wanted to represent Wheels as a class then it wouldn't make sense to say that Wheels IS a Car. A car HAS wheels. So Wheels Class should be an instance variable in Car.
So back to your example. A Universe HAS galaxies and a Galaxy HAS planets. But a planet IS NOT a galaxy and a galaxy IS NOT a Universe.

Comment: Very minor edit suggestion: Say "Maserati", not "A Maserati"; "A Maserati" would be an instance of the Maserati class, but the concept/blueprint for "A Maserati" would be the class itself.

Answer (score 2):

So, your first problem here is trying to make a class hierarchy of something that is fundamentally not suitable for it. When you're inheriting from another class, ask yourself "Is a *SubClass* a type of *Class*?". In your case, "Is a Galaxy a type of Universe?" and "Is a Planet a type of Galaxy?" are both clearly false.

In the cases you've got here, all the classes should *contain* the lower level types; a `Universe` might contain a `list` of `Galaxy`s, which in turn contain a `list` of `Planet`s. I don't know exactly what you mean by a `PlanetType` here (it seems perfectly possible for a `Planet` to have an attribute, possibly an `enum.Enum`, describing the type and a `list` of resources), so I doubt it's a case for a subclass, but if it really is useful (e.g. you need methods that appear on all `Planet`s but behave differently by the type), it might be reasonable to declare:

```
class GasGiant(Planet):
    ...
class RockyPlanet(Planet):
    ...
```

or the like, since "Is a GasGiant a type of Planet?" does in fact have an answer of "Yes". That said, I'd be wary of changing the prototype of the initializer even then; look up [the Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle). Basically, you never want to be in a scenario where something expects a `Planet` (that might really be one of the subclasses) but only works on some of the three `Planet` classes, breaking if passed a different one.

Comment: Fantastic, I didn't expect all these awesome answers like this right away. THANKS GUYS!

Answer (score 0):

This doesnt make sense for the reasons listed in the other answers (the car one is the one I like).

However it *could* make sense to have a base class, say SpaceObject (bogus name on purpose, naming is *hard*). This would have a *position* and *size* field.  Those are common to Galaxy, Planet, etc…

In general, when you strongly suspect you’ll have commonality between object classes, create a base class and then gradually move fields/methods into it, from specialized subclasses as the case for reuse becomes apparent.  Don't overdo this but it can be useful.

(Universe is harder to pin down in this respect).

The subclasses could also track a “located_in” *class*. Galaxy-> Universe.

About planets and subclasses… That’s one possibility, to have subclasses (via OOP *inheritance*).  Another is to use OOP *[composition](https://realpython.com/inheritance-composition-python/)* instead.  Planet has size, mass, temperature, gravity numeric fields.  Plus say an Atmosphere field. And Core field. Hard to say with planets, but if you were modelling say Dogs, class hierarchies are quickly a lousy way to track size, hair type, barking, etc… across breeds.